# Rails active record query getting most common objects

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to query a model to get the most common field of a certain attributeso far I have

```
 Person.maximum('age')
```

But how do I query a group of lets say 6 of the most common ages.
Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to group persons by their ages and pick the group with the highest count. The code below will return both age and frequency of most frequent age.

```
Person.group('age').order('count_all').limit(1).count
```

To fetch the age only and not the count do

```
Person.group('age').order('count(*)').limit(1).pluck(:age).first
```

Comment: How do I get it to show without the count just the first values