# Get the most common column value between all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to return the most common text value (country) from the database.

Whilst my first attempt is not producing any errors, I suspect it's not returning the most common value:

```
@mostpopularroast = Roast.group(:id).order("count(country) DESC").first
```

Interesting it gives me the exact same result should I use ASC instead.

I'm therefore now trying a solution from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136321/rails-active-record-query-getting-most-common-objects):

```
@mostpopularroast = Roast.group('country').order('count(*)').limit(1).pluck(:country).first
```

But this is giving me the error `undefined method 'country' for "Country 1":String`. `Country 1` being the value in the db.

**my model**

```
class CreateRoasts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :roasts do |t|
      t.string :roaster
      t.string :name
      t.string :country
      t.string :region
      t.string :bestfor
      t.string :beans
      t.string :roast
      t.string :slug


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply descending ordering to get the most popular `country`:

```
Roast.group(:country).select(:country).order("count(*) desc").first.country
```

Your initial error is not related to this, it is just that you are using `pluck`, which returns `Array` object, then you are calling `first` method on it and getting `String` object, which is the object that is already the name of the most popular roast country, but then you are trying to call `country` on it, which results in the exception.

Comment: This complains I need to be grouping on `:id`. And doing so just takes me back to the original error.

Comment: @SimonCooper: You don't need to be grouping on `:id` in case this is the exact query you are using

Comment: @SimonCooper it would help if you posted the query you are running and the generated sql query output

Comment: I'm just doing this from the UI

Comment: @SimonCooper: the code posted in my answer is already giving your the string value you want btw, you don't need to call `country`one more time

Comment: unfortunately not. it gives the following `PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "roasts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "roasts".* FROM "roasts" GROUP BY "roasts"."country"... ^ : SELECT "roasts".* FROM "roasts" GROUP BY "roasts"."country" ORDER BY count(*) desc LIMIT $1`

Comment: it worked with `Roast.group(:country).select(:country).order("count(*) desc").first`.  Thanks!